# High memory pressure in generator with random.sample()

Tags: python, random, generator, random-seed, memory-pressure

**DISCLAIMER (added later): I have modified the code to take into account @jasonharper and @user2357112supportsMonica comments here below. Still having the memory issue.**

I'm running the following code:

```
import itertools
from tqdm import tnrange
import random

def perm_generator(comb1, comb2):
    seen = set()
    length1 = len(comb1)
    length2 = len(comb2)
    while True:
        perm1 = tuple(random.sample(comb1, length1))
        perm2 = tuple(random.sample(comb2, length2))
        perm_pair = perm1 + perm2
        if ( (perm_pair not in seen) ):
            seen.add(perm_pair)
            yield [perm1,perm2]            


seq_all = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V') 
combinations_first_half = list(itertools.combinations(seq_all, int(len(seq_all)/2)))

n = 1000
random.seed(0)
all_rand_permutations = []
for i in tnrange(len(combinations_first_half), desc = 'rand_permutations'):
    comb1 = combinations_first_half[i]
    comb2 = tuple(set(seq_all) - set(comb1))
    gen = perm_generator(comb1,comb2)
    rand_permutations = [next(gen) for _ in range(n)]
    all_rand_permutations += rand_permutations
```

and for almost all the iterations of the for loop everything goes smoothly with about 33 iterations per second.

However, in some rare cases, the loop gets stuck and begins to build memory pressure for quite a few seconds. Eventually, on a given later iteration the kernel dies.

It seems to be related with `random.sample()` because if I start the loop from the index relative to the iteration in which the kernel dies or one of the high memory pressure iterations (hence, somehow consequently shifting the `random.seed()`), there is no issue and the loop goes through it like for the other fast iterations.

I attach here a few screenshots:

[image: Iteration building high memory pressure]

[image: Iteration with no problem]

[image: Iteration in which the Kernel dies]

Comment: `[next(perm_generator(comb1,comb2)) for _ in range(n)]` doesn't do what you seem to expect it to.  That's *not* extracting 1000 results from a single generator; you're creating the generator 1000 times, and extracting a single result from each.  In other words, your `seen` set is pointless, because you never generate a second result to check against it.

Comment: @jasonharper, you are right. I think I can solve the issue of not using ```seen``` by initializing it right before ```rand_permutations = [next(perm_generator(comb1,comb2)) for _ in range(n)]``` and removing its initialization from within ```perm_generator```.

However, I do want the generator to be called 1000 times for each for-loop-iteration.

Question: your comment was also related to the memory issue or you just wanted to point to the problem with ```seen```?

Comment: You perhaps want to call `next()` on a single generator 1000 times.  Creating 1000 different generators, and calling `next()` on each one once, is absurd - there's no point in them even being generators, they might as well be a plain function that returns a single value.  (Until the code is actually doing what you want it to be doing, I don't see much point in worrying about the memory issue.)

Comment: @jasonharper, are you suggesting to put: ```gen = perm_generator(comb1,comb2)``` before ```rand_permutations = [next(gen) for _ in range(n)]```?

Comment: @jasonharper, if you are suggesting what's in the above comment, I think (I might be wrong) that is equivalent. I believe that in my original list comprehension the generator is created only once and called 1000 times. And, I would still be interested to understand the memory issue from the original code, nevertheless; because it's an "odd" behavior and I would like to understand why that's happening.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting.  The expression before the `for` in a list comprehension gets evaluated every iteration; that included a call to `perm_generator()`, so it was creating a new generator.

Comment: @jasonharper, after moving ```seen``` out of the generator, I checked if it was correctly working while still using ```[next(perm_generator(comb1,comb2)) for _ in range(n)]``` and it did. My impression was that the generator was called only once in the list comprehension. In all cases, I have modified the code as per your suggestion (also in the question here above) and I still have the same memory pressure issue.

Comment: Why did you move `seen` out of the generator? (And why did you switch to using a list instead of a set?) Neither of those things were part of jasonharper's suggestion. Moving `seen` out of the generator makes it much less reusable, and switching to a list slows things down with no benefit.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, you are right. I'll modify the code again in the question. But please, anyone has a suggestion on the main question regarding the memory pressure? After having tried the suggestions to modify the code, I still have the memory pressure issue.

Comment: The difference in swap used looks suspicious.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, what's the difference in swap? Is it this: ```comb2 = tuple(set(seq_all) - set(comb1))```?

Comment: No, look at the "Swap Used" display in the memory monitor thingy. The one with the green graph is using a ton of swap.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, it might be as simple as a memory accumulation in ```all_rand_permutations += rand_permutations```? I see that it's accumulating memory in the App Memory and then, after the Physical Memory is exhausted, it starts to fill up the Swap. However, I still don't understand why the memory pressure goes up only for certain iterations...

Comment: To anyone interested, I verified that ```all_rand_permutations += rand_permutations``` was the issue.